# Different application pools running under the same AD user account - how to distiguish in Task Manager?

Tags: iis, application-pool, taskmanager

We have several application pools all running under the same AD user account.

In Windows Task Manager they all look like:

w3wp.exe (Image Name)      AppPoolUser (User Name)

Is there some way to match these to their corresponding web applications to be able to tell with one is consuming a lot of memory (or CPU resources)?

Comment: using [`appcmd`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc772200(v=ws.10).aspx) you can list the worker process pid's on each site and then cross-reference with task manager.

Comment: @TZHX: can you be more specific on what command to use? "appcmd list app" doesn't provide worker process pid for each application (note that they are different applications running on the same site)

Comment: ah, I use `appcmd list wps` which tell me the application pool for each process. my applications have a 1:1 mapping to pools (for this reason), but all the pools use the same identity. if you have multiple sites using the same application pool I don't think there's a way to split up what is used by what.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old but this may help someone. An easy way could be, in "Task Manager" to you can show the "Command line" Column in the "Details" Tab and if the AppPools are all named differently (even though they all use the same AD account) you can see the AppPool name in this column e.g.:

Task Manage View:

> Image Name | User Name   | Command line 
> w3wp.exe      | AppPoolUser | C:\windows\system32\inetsv\w3wp.exe -ap "**AppPoolName**".....